# WindowBuilder equivalent for IntelliJ?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

There is a plugin for Eclipse called WindowBuilder. Is there an equivalent for IntelliJ?

Comment: @duffymo You are wrong, **you don't like** Eclipse, which is a different thing. Every IDE is good, as it does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Don't use a GUI builder; it's bad practice and you aren't learning anything. Not to mention that the code generation is horrific.

Comment: @JoshM : I would disagree. There are good UI builders (like the ones I've mentioned) and it greatly helps to learn by watching they generated - especially if one doesn't have the luxury of too much time or a good teacher. Besides they allow even newbies to do very good layouts or prototype quickly.

Comment: @Hans _Besides they allow even newbies to do very good layouts or prototype quickly._ IMHO, this is the basic problem. One should know what he's doing, so using builders without knowing what code is generated and _why_ it's generated is really bad, one should first learn how to do something, and _then_ use builders to simplify the job

Comment: @Hans I don't believe there is any benefit to using a GUI builder in a non-work environment (which is obviously the case here) because you determine how productive you are. As BackSlash is pointing, you should never write a piece of code without fully understanding its meaning and this seems to be a major issue with GUI builder users. They are seemingly dragging and dropping without knowing what it means at all.

Comment: @BackSlash I'm not saying that the user should not learn, but they're also great for learning, allowing the user to quickly experiment with the various properties of a control and get the feedback without restarting. This immediate feedback speeds allot. See Bret Victor's "Immediate Connection" presentation.

Comment: The point of programming tools is to make a program that works, not to ensure people are doing the best possible thing with the greatest possible understanding.  GUI builders are fine - the application is the product, not the code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

IntelliJ has it's own GUI Builder: 
   http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/gui_builder.html

But there are also 3rd party plug-ins.

The best so far that can work standalone or as a plug-in for IntelliJ, Eclipse, Netbeans etc. is JFormDesigner: http://www.formdev.com/

JFormDesigner is the best UI Designer I've tried so far: just take a look at the demos.

Comment: JFormDesigner looks quite nice. I'll have to try that out too. Hopefully it doesn't use intermediate XML files like Matisse, since that's the current issue I'm trying to run away from.

Comment: No it's not like WindowBuilder ,  WB gives you freedom to build your GUI your way. INtellij's default builder forces you to use specific config ( like using .form files ) and you cannot use some layouts like AbsoluteLayout ( null layout ) .

Comment: JFormDesigner is paid, there is 20 days of "free" but you need to pay with your data for that. WindowBuilder is excellent, but it is only for Eclipse. The solution could be to open the project in Eclipse and intelliJ both at the same time, then edit GUI in eclipse and code in IntelliJ.