# Eclipse: Disable auto completion but keep showing suggestions

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, intellij-idea, eclipse-plugin

After a long period of creating apps with Android Studio I returned to Eclipse to program a pure Java application. Of course, I have noticed large differences in terms of auto completion between IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse but IntelliJ is no alternative for me because of various reasons.

That is why I started to change the settings in Eclipse, inter alia, for the content assist. I want to have suggestions for variable names too, without having to write a dot first. As you can see in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24Axk.png) image, I have changed the auto activation triggers to `._@abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` as suggested in another thread on Stack Overflow.

The problem is, if I write short variable names like `d` it completes them automatically to something different (in this case `DEFAULT_CURSOR`) when I press the dot key. To avoid this, I have to choose the variable first, before pressing the dot key.

However, having to do it this way is a large waste of time. Is there a possibility to use the suggested variables or methods only when I have pressed the enter key, just like in IntelliJ?

Maybe there is an option to bind the dot key to the closing of the content assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Eclipse and IntelliJ are different and IntelliJ's level of auto completion is unique to itself. If you are comfortable with it, you should use it and then copy and paste to eclipse for windowbuilder. Also FYI there **is** a free alternative to windowbuilder for IntelliJ, you can read about it here: [WindowBuilder equivalent for IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562440/windowbuilder-equivalent-for-intellij)